# UniObjects for Java read object code file

Tags: java, universe, uniobjects

I am reading from a UniVerse database using UniObjects for Java using the `UniFile.read()` method. This is an example of the type of code I use for this.

```
...
UniFile uFile = uSession.open ("ORDERS");
UniDataSet datasetRequest = getUnidatasetRequest();
UniDataSet datasetResult = uFile.read(datasetRequest);  
...
```

For most queries this works, but when I try to read an object file (eg `SOMEFILE.O`), this read truncates the records within the file. I am thinking that the special characters in the object code are causing problems.

Is there a way to read object code records using UniObjects for Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we ended up doing:

I couldn't find a way to make the dataset read the binary code, so I read the items one at a time using a subroutine. Before the items could be read I had to install and run a UniBasic subroutine on the database to encode the item into base 64 using something like this:

```
...

LOOP
    READBLK A.BYTE FROM FILE, 1 THEN NULL ELSE DONE = TRUE
UNTIL DONE DO
    TO.ENCODE = TO.ENCODE : A.BYTE
REPEAT
ENCODE('Base64', 1, TO.ENCODE, 1, RET.VALUE, 1)

...
```

This subroutine returned the base 64 encoded item as a `String`to UOJ and then it could be decoded and no data was lost. Here is an example of the Java Code:

```
...
UniSubroutine readBlkSub = unisession.subroutine(routineName, 4);
readBlkSub.setArg(0, getNameID());
readBlkSub.setArg(1, itemName);
readBlkSub.call();
final String SUCCESS = "0";
if (readBlkSub.getArg(3).equals(SUCCESS)) {
    encodedObjectCode = readBlkSub.getArg(2);
    sun.misc.BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(encodedObjectCode);
    ...
}
```